# Compiling Javascript to wasm

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I am trying to compile javascript to wasm using [Javy](https://github.com/Shopify/javy). Javy is a JavaScript to WebAssembly toolchain. It takes your JavaScript code and executes it in a WebAssembly embedded JavaScript runtime.

So when I am trying to install build and development dependencies. In it, there is wasi-sdk and I am downloading it by running `make download-wasi-sdk`

But I am getting error like:

```
ajit0902@AJITPC:/mnt/c/Users/msi/javy$ make download-wasi-sdk
./install-wasi-sdk.sh
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:5: download-wasi-sdk] Error 127
```

Comment: When I see `bash\r` It makes me think that you have Windows-style `\r\n` line endings in your `.sh` file.  Especially since I see `/mnt/c` there's some mixed Windows-Linux things going on no doubt.  Your .sh file must have linux-style `\n`-only  line endings.

Comment: Did you git-clone this from windows by any chance? Delete it and clone it again from within WSL.

Comment: Maybe you git-cloned in Windows (your git client put \r\n line endings on all the text files).  The git client can be set to preserve line endings for .sh files with `*.sh text eol=lf` in the .gitattributes file.  But it's probably not your repo to make such a change.  (Just clone in WSL like tkausl says.)

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings